# How to implement ItemAnimator of RecyclerView to disable the animation of notifyItemChanged

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

In my project I need disable the "change" animation of `RecyclerView` while `notifyItemChanged`.

I investigated in the source of `RecyclerView` and had overridden `android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator` as below:

```
private static  class ItemAnimator extends DefaultItemAnimator
{
    @Override
    public boolean animateChange(RecyclerView.ViewHolder oldHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder newHolder, int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY) {
        if(oldHolder != null)
        {
            oldHolder.itemView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            dispatchChangeFinished(oldHolder, true);
        }

        if(newHolder != null)
        {
            dispatchChangeFinished(newHolder, false);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

But I am not sure if I match the spec of the Google document:
[`RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.animateChange`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html#animateChange(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

According to my understanding source code, if I do not override the method properly, the oldHolder **will not** be recycled.

Please help me figure out how to override `animateChange` in a correct way.

Comment: See here for the correct solution to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42969391/2220337

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766497/disable-onchange-animations-on-itemanimator-for-recyclerview

Answer (score 123, accepted):

I have found the correct solution to just remove the animateChange.

It's very simple. Google has implemented the functionality.

```
((SimpleItemAnimator) RecyclerView.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
```

Documentation: [setSupportsChangeAnimations](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html#setSupportsChangeAnimations%28boolean%29)

Comment: It's also defined in *DefaultItemAnimator* and you can do it in this way: `((DefaultItemAnimator) recyclerView.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);`

Comment: This broke the item move animations for DiffUtil.Result.dispatchChanges for me.

Comment: @Mavamaarten try `recyclerView.getItemAnimator().setChangeDuration(0)`, work for me.

Answer (score 55):

I had the same problem. When calling notifyItemChanged there was a red overlay flashing. After experimenting around with your code I finally removed the default Animator by simply calling

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```

on the RecyclerView.

Comment: recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);

Will remove all animation of RecyclerView. I only want to remove animateChange.

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 8):

@Kenny answer didn't work anymore because google remove method `setSupportsChangeAnimations()` (but why?) in support library 23.1.0.

In some case `setChangeDuration(0)` can work as workaround.

@edit
I suggest use something like that:

```
  RecyclerView.ItemAnimator animator = recyclerView.getItemAnimator();
        if (animator instanceof SimpleItemAnimator) {
            ((SimpleItemAnimator) animator).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
        }
```

Comment: so you basically using the same method after a sugar instanceof ?

Comment: At this moment my post no have any sense because Kenny post was edited after i wrote my own. Previous kenny implementation it's not working on 23.1.0+  support library so i paste own solution for it.

Comment: This method is present in current Support library, see [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SimpleItemAnimator.html#setSupportsChangeAnimations(boolean)). Also, it is present in Android X packages. What are you talking about?

Answer (score 8):

Just if someone stumbles like me: 
 Somehow `setSupportsChangeAnimations(false)` didn't work for me, but `recyclerView.getItemAnimator().setChangeDuration(0)` has just removed the animation nicely.

Answer (score 5):

If found a solution, for everyone who wants to keep all the animations given by the DefaultItemAnimator, but getting rid of the "blink" animation that occurs every time the view is updated.

First, get the source code of DefaultItemAnimator. Create a class with the same name in your project.

Second, set the ItemAnimator to a new instance of your modified DefaultItemAnimator, like so:

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new MyItemAnimator());
```

Then, go in the new classes source code and locate the method

```
animateChangeImpl(final ChangeInfo changeInfo) { ... }
```

Now, we simply have to locate the method calls changing alpha values. Find the following two lines and remove the .alpha(0) and .alpha(1)

```
oldViewAnim.alpha(0).setListener(new VpaListenerAdapter() { ... }
newViewAnimation.translationX(0).translationY(0).setDuration(getChangeDuration()).alpha(1).setListener(new VpaListenerAdapter() { ... }
```

like so

```
oldViewAnim.setListener(new VpaListenerAdapter() { ... }
newViewAnimation.translationX(0).translationY(0).setDuration(getChangeDuration()).setListener(new VpaListenerAdapter() { ... }
```

Comment: when calling `notifyItemRangeChanged` it is blinking after this changes

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution is to extend `DefaultItemAnimator` and set `setSupportsChangeAnimations` to `false` right in the constructor:

```
public class DefaultItemAnimatorNoChange extends DefaultItemAnimator {
    public DefaultItemAnimatorNoChange() {
        setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've created an Extention Class, to disable animation

```
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.SimpleItemAnimator

fun RecyclerView.disableAnimation() {
    (itemAnimator as? SimpleItemAnimator)?.supportsChangeAnimations = false
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
recyclerView.disableAnimation()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple and an efficient way to do this:

```
public class NoAnimAnimator extends DefaultItemAnimator {
    public NoAnimAnimator() {
        setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
        setChangeDuration(0);
    }
}
```

And in your recyclerview, add the animator:

```
recylerview.setItemAnimator(new NoAnimAnimator());
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score -1):

Nothing of the above solutions worked for me. What worked was using the **TransitionManager** and setting the **scene** transition to null

```
TransitionManager.go(new Scene(recyclerView), null);
```

To **re-enable** the default animation you can create a new **AutoTransition** and set it to the same method above:

```
AutoTransition autoTransition = new AutoTransition();
TransitionManager.go(new Scene(recyclerView), autoTransition);
```