# Disable scroll animation in RecyclerView

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` which basically does nothing other than scroll programmatically. The problem is I need this `RecyclerView` to scroll to position with no animation. This is the code I'm using.

```
((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, offset);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `RecyclerView` doesn't have a 'scrollable' attribute by the look of it. Also I don't actually want to stop scrolling just want to disable the animation when scrollTo is called.

Comment: check this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29873859/how-to-implement-itemanimator-of-recyclerview-to-disable-the-animation-of-notify

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. But no luck.

Answer (score -1):

You can animate itemView yourself,
use two variable `startPosition` and `endPosition` for starting position and end position and `animate(viewHolder, false)` is a function where you can add or remove animation

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        final DataModel dataModel = dataList.get(position);

        viewHolder.textTittle.setText(dataModel .getTitle());    

        if (startPosition <=position  && position<= endPosition) {
            animate(viewHolder, false);
        } else {
            animate(viewHolder, true);
        }    

    }
```

animate function like

```
public void animate(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
            final Animation animAnticipateOvershoot = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
                    R.anim.animator_for_bounce);
            viewHolder.itemView.setAnimation(animAnticipateOvershoot);
        }
```

Comment: I don't actually want to animate it, scrolling animation when I use `scrollToPosition()`.