# Disable animation in notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I'm trying to change the visibility of `ImageView` (Visible/Invisible), depending on the RecyclerView item state (Selected/Not selected), so if the item selected, I want to make `ImageView` visible, something like the below picture :

I wrote the following code to make this true :

```
    private int selectedItem = 0;

    public class ViewHolderFilters extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        CircleImageView img;
        CircleImageView selected_effect;

        ViewHolderFilters(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            img = itemView.findViewById(R.id._imageView);
            selected_effect = itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_effect);
            img.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        void onBindView(int position) {
            final String s = spacecrafts.get(position);
            Glide.with(c)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(s).centerCrop()
                    .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.transparent_icon))
                    .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            img.setImageBitmap(setEffectLight(c, resource, getThumbnail(bitmapOriginal)));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                        }
                    });
            if (selected_item == position) {
                selected_effect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                selected_effect.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            monShaderRecyclerViewClickListener.onClick(view, spacecrafts.get(getAdapterPosition()));
            selected_item = getAdapterPosition();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

**MY ISSUE:**

Each time I select an item, the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method brings an animation with it, which looks not smooth and nice.

How I can disable the animation and update the item?

Comment: are you using ListAdapter from the recyclerview lib?

Comment: @sonnet, thank you for your comment, no I did not

Comment: try updating only that item instead of updating the entire list. `notifyItemChanged(selected_item)`. If that doesn't work then look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29873859/how-to-implement-itemanimator-of-recyclerview-to-disable-the-animation-of-notify

Comment: @sonnet, I've tried the `notifyItemChanged(selected_item)`, another issue appears, the `selected_effect` keeps visible on all selected items

Answer (score 2):

There is a default item animator on recycler view. You can disable it when creating the recycler view inside your view/fragment/activity:

```
((DefaultItemAnimator) recyclerView.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, unfortunately, the animation keeps appears every time I select an item